# Laravel 5.4 – error while creating facade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

This is how I create helper (App\Helpers\Settings.php)

```
namespace App\Helpers;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Settings {

    protected $settings = [];

    public function __construct() {

        $this->settings['AppName'] = 'Test';
    }

    /**
     * Fetch all values
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAll () {
        return $this->settings;
    }
}
```

Creating facade (App\Helpers\Facades\SettingsFacade.php)

```
namespace App\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class Settings extends Facade {

    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() {
        return 'Settings';
    }
}
```

Creating Service Provider (App\Providers\SettingsServiceProvider.php)

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class SettingsServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application events.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot() {
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register() {
        App::bind( 'Settings', function () {
            return new \App\Helpers\Settings;
        });
    }  */
}
```

Registering provider (App\Providers\SettingsServiceProvider::class)

Creating alias: `'Settings'   => App\Facades\Settings::class`

Running `composer dump-autoload`

Trying to use facade `Settings::getAll();`

Getting error Class `'App\Http\Controllers\Settings' not found`

Can’t figure out why I cannot create facade and getting that error

Comment: it's because of namespaces, try: `\Settings::getAll();`

Comment: Class 'App\Facades\Settings' not found

Comment: rename
`App\Helpers\Facades\SettingsFacade.php`
to
`App\Helpers\Facades\Settings.php`

helps to call call `\Settings::getAll();`

but how do I call like `Settings::getAll();`

Comment: if you wan't to call it like `Settings::getAll();` you need to add `use Settings` at the top of file.

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

App\Helpers\Settings.php

```
namespace App\Helpers;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    class Settings {

        protected $settings = [];

        public function __construct() {

            $this->settings['AppName'] = 'Test';
        }

        /**
         * Fetch all values
         *
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function getAll () {
            return $this->settings;
        }
    }
```

App/Http/Controllers/XyzController.php

```
use Facades\App\Settings;
class XyzController extends Controller
{
     public function showView()
     {
         return Settings::getAll();
     }
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/','XyzController@showView');

use Facades\App\Helpers\Settings;

Route::get('/direct',function() {
    return Settings::getAll();
});
```

use laravel [Real time facades](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/facades#real-time-facades)